# Xcode Project Folder Structure

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using the latest XCode / Swift 3.0 and facing some problems:

I created a folder in /MyProject/MyProject/Assets/Subfolder1 and stored a few hundred .txt files in it to iterate over the files inside the Subfolder1 with the following code:

```
let fm = FileManager.default
fm.enumerator(atPath: "/MyProject/Assets/Subfolder1")?.forEach({ (e) in
    if let e = e as? String, let url = URL(string: e) {
        doSomethingWith(url.pathExtension)
    }
})
```

But I cannot find any files. I tried some variations ("/Assets/Subfolder1/" and "/MyProject/MyProject/Assets/Subfolder1"), all are not working.

**What is the correct path that I have to specify?**

Best
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, make sure you have added the actual folder to the Xcode project. You can do this simply by dragging and dropping the folder into your project. After you drag and drop, this window should appear

[image: Add file window]

Make sure you select `Create folder references` and `Copy items if needed`. This will make sure that the entire folder is constantly synced inside your Xcode project. Then to verify that the assets will be transferred to your device when building the project, go into `Build Phases` and then to `Copy Bundle Resources` and you should see the name of the folder, in my case, I have named it `TextFiles`.

[image]

Now because you have added your folder into the application's Main Bundle, you can access it by doing this:

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath?.appending("/TextFiles")
fm.enumerator(atPath: path!)?.forEach({ (e) in
    if let e = e as? String, let url = URL(string: e) {
        doSomethingWith(url.pathExtension)
    }
})
```

The reason we need to do the `Bundle.main.resourcePath` before it and can't simply say `/TextFiles` is because if we say `/TextFiles` it looks for that folder starting from the system root, which is why it wasn't working before. It would be like having a folder in `C:/Users/Abc123/Documents/TextFiles` but the system is looking for it in `C:/TextFiles`.

Comment: I redid this 2 times. Unfortunately this is not working too :/

Comment: updated my answer, i tested it on my machine and it was working. let me know if you have any issues